# How to use inline CKEditor in an iframe correctly?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

I am trying to use the inline CKEditor on contenteditable divs that are located in an iframe. I found a way which works basically like this:

**JavaScript**

```
var myFrame = Document.getElementById('myIframeId');
var contenteditableElement = myFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('editorDivId')
CKEDITOR.inline(contenteditableElement);
```

But there are two drawbacks:

- The initial position of the toolbar is wrong.
- The toolbar does not respond on scroll events of the iframe. It stays fixed at the initial position.

I created [a fiddle to demonstrate the unwanted behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/benson175/Fs5Ws/6/).

Here you can compare how the toolbar positioning should behave: http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline

Is there anything I can do to improve the positioning of the toolbar?

Comment: Please don't rely on links which might not always be there. Stack Overflow is not a help forum, it's Q&A resource; questions and answers should be self-contained so that they'll be useful for future readers.

Comment: To be frank, CKEditor has never been designed to work this way, that is – inside of an iframe. You'd need to modify the code of [Floatingspace plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/floatingspace), which is responsible for rendering the toolbar, to create it in the document in which editor instance currently resides (inside of an iframe – `editor.document`) instead of the global document (`CKEDITOR.document`). I've never tried that but I wish you luck ;)

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I am in the same position as you- the toolbar doesn't react to the position of the iframe. Would love a solution to this issue.

Comment: No, I didn't found a solution for this problem. As an alternative idea, I used the ckeditors sharedspaces plugin to display the toolbar in a fixed position outside the iframe. But of course, this solution has some other drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

i've find this solution:

```
    //The inline editor should be enabled on an element with "contenteditable" attribute set to "true".
    //Otherwise CKEditor will start in read-only mode.

    $("#html_template").bind('load', function() {
        function loadScript(url, callback)
        {
            // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
            var head = this.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = this.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = url;

            // Then bind the event to the callback function.
            // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
            script.onreadystatechange = callback;
            script.onload = callback;

            // Fire the loading
            head.appendChild(script);
        }

       function e(){
        var alleditableElement = this.getElementsByClassName("editable");

        $(alleditableElement).each(function(i,v){

            v.setAttribute( 'contenteditable', true );

            document.getElementById('html_template').contentWindow.CKEDITOR.inline(v,{ toolbar : [ { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic'] }, { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList' ] } ] });

        });
        };
        var iframedoc=document.getElementById('html_template').contentWindow.document;
        iframedoc.loadScript=loadScript;
        iframedoc.e=e;
        iframedoc.loadScript('http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.6/standard-all/ckeditor.js',function(){iframedoc.e()});
    });
```

Launch this code in document ready.

Comment: Add id "html_template" to your iframe